# SQL set column to row count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using a SQL Server database and have two tables with the following columns:

`Driver: DriverID, NumCars`

`Cars: CarID, DriverID`

`NumCars` is empty, but I need it to be the count of rows in `Cars` that contain that particular `DriverID`. How would I do this?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: are you just trying to update it once, and store it in the `NumCars` column? or are you trying to just fetch the count as part of querying `Driver`

Comment: You are looking for `JOIN`

Comment: @JiggsJedi I haven't tried anything yet. I'm new to SQL and didn't know where to start with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the count of `Cars` that belong to a driver, along with all `Driver` data with the following `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT *
    ,(
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Cars c
        WHERE c.DriverID = d.DriverID
        )
FROM Driver d
```

You can `UPDATE` the `NumCars` column with the following statement:

```
UPDATE Driver
SET NumCars = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Cars
    WHERE Driver.DriverID = Cars.DriverID
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT count(carID) as CountOfCars from Cars where DriverID = [DriverID]
```

Will give you the count based on input DriverID
or

```
SELECT DriverId, count(carID) as CountOfCars from Cars group by DriverID
```

Will give you all counts of carIDs and group them by DriverID

If you need to base the counts on the data from the Driver table:

```
SELECT count(carID) as CountOfCars from Cars inner join on Driver.DriverID = Cars.DriverID group by Cars.DriverID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE D
  SET D.NumCars = C.NumCars
FROM Driver D INNER JOIN (SELECT DriverID, COUNT(*) AS NumCars
                          FROM Cars
                          GROUP BY DriverID) C
ON D.DriverID = C.DriverID
```

Answer (score 0):

This will set all entries of the `NumCars` column in the `Driver` table to the number of cars associated with that driver:

```
UPDATE Driver SET NumCars = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Cars WHERE Driver.DriverID = Cars.DriverID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do a subquery, then JOIN that to the table you want to update.

```
UPDATE  d
SET     NumCars = [NumCars]
FROM    Driver AS d
        INNER JOIN (SELECT  d.DriverID, COUNT(c.CarID) AS NumCars
                FROM    Drivers AS d
                        INNER JOIN Cars AS c ON c.DriverID = d.DriverID
                GROUP BY d.DriverID 
                ) AS Sub ON sub.DriverID = a.DriverID
```

Comment: that seems.. excessively complex.

Comment: I can see that @arserbin3.  I don't like subqueries in my SELECTs or SET statements.  Just habit.

Comment: That seems to make it harder to notice errors in code, such as `Sub.NumCars` and `[NumOfCars]`. But definitely useful if setting multiple aggregated columns at once

Answer (score 0):

If you want the updation of the column to be dynamic, create an after insert/update trigger on the second table and inside that trigger, you can update the first table's column by using any one of the above mentioned approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. It works.

```
update Driver
set Driver.Numcars = src.cnt
from
(
select c.DriverId, count(c.CarId) as cnt
from Cars as c
inner join Driver as d
on c.DriverId = d.DriverId
group by c.DriverId
) as src
where Driver.DriverId = src.DriverId
```